# How can I change ios view when connection did finish receiving the data?

Tags: ios, ios6, uiviewcontroller, nsurlconnection

In this application when user presses a button a url request will be sent to a server and some corresponding data will be received by the application.

My problem is I want to receive the data completely from the server and when the connection did finished receiving the data, change the view and pass the received data to the other view.

After the conversion of data I receive error and app crashes.

I tried this approach but don't know what should I do exactly.

*Problem Solved and Code is Edited*

```
 #import "ViewController.h"
@interface ViewController ()
//@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableData *responseData;

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize responseData;
@synthesize myTableView;
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
NSLog(@"viewdidload");
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
  [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {

   NSLog(@"Response received From the server.");
  [self.responseData setLength:0];
}
  - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {

  NSLog(@"appending data to the response object.");
  [self.responseData appendData:data];

}
 - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {

   NSLog(@"didFailWithError");
   NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Connection failed: %@", [error description]]);
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
     NSLog(@"Loading data succeeded! Received %d bytes of data", 
       [self.responseData length]);
     //call the converter to convert the received 
     //Data to Json Packet and save to variable
     [self convertDataToJson];
      [self changePage];

 }
 -(void)changePage {
      resultsTableViewController *myTableView = [[resultsTableViewController  alloc]init];
       myTableView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
        myTableView=[myTableView init];
        [self presentViewController:myTableView animated:YES completion:NULL];

 }


-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
  {
   resultsTableViewController *mytable = [segue destinationViewController];
   NSMutableArray * response = self.responseArray;
   mytable.responseArray = response;

   }

- (IBAction)get:(id)sender {


  //making an instance of data query object and passing the word and dictionary selection to it.
   if ( ![[searchField text]isEqualToString:@""] )
   {
       word = @”test”
       [self makeRequestForWord:word withDictionaryName:@""];
       // NSData *query = [word dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  }
 }



-(void)makeRequestForWord:(NSString*)word withDictionaryName:(NSString*)dicSelect;
{

    //creating URL Request Object using given URL object.
    //It requests data using nsConnection

}


- (void)convertDataToJson
{
// some conversion and save into responseDATA
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
   [super viewDidUnload];
}
@end
```

And then in function related to segue I'll send the object to the next view.

Comment: Impossible to say without more code (suggest pasting the whole class in) and the details of your crash.

Comment: Post the error message.

Comment: I added all the important sections from .m file.

Comment: The `responseData` property is commented out. Do you actually have a `@property` for this?

Comment: what's the error you are getting?

Comment: would the error be coming from the fact that `connectionDidFinishLoading` is asynchronous, so it may be having trouble getting a reference to the correct object/view?

Comment: Yes I have that property in .h File....

Comment: @HRM: ** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present a nil modal view controller on target <ViewController: 0x75569d0>.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1c9a012 0x10d7e7e 0x105111 0x106167 0x28f8 0x2812 0xbdd589 0xbdb652 0xbdc89a 0xbdb60d 0xbdb785 0xb28a68 0x461c911 0x461bbb3 0x4659cda 0x1c3c8fd 0x465a35c 0x465a2d5 0x4544250 0x1c1df3f 0x1c1d96f 0x1c40734 0x1c3ff44 0x1c3fe1b 0x1bf47e3 0x1bf4668 0x1bffc 0x203d 0x1f65)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
 This is the error

Comment: The thing is I know that when it finishes the receiving data... the data is perfectly correct... but I don't know how to change the view... I just noticed I cant just try to change view within the connection Did Finish Loading function... because function will be unfinished and won't reach to it's closing brace... I should do something to try to change the page after exiting _'connectionDidFinishLoading'_ function

Comment: Indicated where the app crashes... In `connectionDidFinishLoading`, commented the crash cause

Comment: From the error, it is clear that myTableView is nil. BTW, what type is myTableView and how its created?

Comment: @HRM : It's created in .h file. I declared it like `@property (strong, nonatomic) resultTableViewController *myTableView;` and obviously I have `resultTableviewController` class with corresponding .h and .m files.

Comment: Tnx every body problem solved. I'll Update my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be presenting the view controller in connectionDidFinishLoading: since it appears that you have a segue set up for the controller -- it's crashing there because you haven't created myTable yet (declaring it in the .h file doesn't create it). The segue will create the instance of your controller, so you should call performSegueWithIdentifier:sender: in connectionDidFinishLoading:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
     NSLog(@"Loading data succeeded! Received %d bytes of data", 
       [self.responseData length]);
     //call the converter to convert the received 
     //Data to Json Packet and save to variable
     [self convertDataToJson];

     [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier" sender:self];
 }
```

Comment: Sorry That  I can't Vote you because of my low reputation :)) <br> by the way I ddidn't setup any segue in storyboard... because I couldn't define for the button to wait until all the data loaded from server and then perform the segue... so I just used the `presentViewController` approach ... I fixed the problem of declaring `myTableView` tnx.

Comment: @user2725916, I assumed you had setup a segue because you implemented prepareForSegue. Why did you do that if you didn't setup a segue? BTW, if you call performSegue from code, you don't need a button in the storyboard -- you make the segue directly from the controller to the other controller, and give it an identifier. Then you can do it like I showed in my answer.

Comment: Actually as I mentioned I didn't want to just load the page until the receiving of data is not finished. I tried doing segue from story board but as soon as clicking the button it was changing the page but I needed to do something else. so I decided to delete the segue from story board. and still don't know how to change the view and pass the arguments with just coding.

Comment: "still don't know how to change the view and pass the arguments with just coding" -- you said in your first comment that you fixed the problem. Doesn't that change the view and pass the data? Did you understand my last comment? You can do this like I show in my answer with a segue, as long as that segue is made from the controller (not a button) -- the segue won't be triggered until you call performSegueWithIdentifier in code, which is done in connectionDidFinishLoading.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation that was really helpful... now I passed it using your suggestion approach too... works perfectly... thank you